# Retrieve full path of attachment from multiple linked tables in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have used union query to select values from other queries

```
   SELECT * FROM 1DBFORM
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM 2DBFORM
    UNION SELECT * FROM 3DBFORM;
```

[image: But when I use UNION QUERY of multiple QUERIES it displays error]
The queries can retrieve the attachment without any error

```
SELECT USERS.NAME, CLIENT_DETAILS.FOLIO_NUMBER, CLIENT_DETAILS.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, CLIENT_DETAILS.ERV, CLIENT_DETAILS.JINA, CLIENT_DETAILS.SLP, AINA_YA_VIWANDA.AINA_YA_VIWANDA, AINA_YA_VIWANDA.ADA, CLIENT_DETAILS.CFULLPATH
FROM AINA_YA_VIWANDA INNER JOIN (USERS INNER JOIN CLIENT_DETAILS ON USERS.ID = CLIENT_DETAILS.UID) ON AINA_YA_VIWANDA.ID = CLIENT_DETAILS.[AINA YA VIWANDA]
ORDER BY CLIENT_DETAILS.FOLIO_NUMBER;
```

.[image: As you can see the image displays the single query 1DBFORM the attachment works well.]
How can I combine the three queries without affecting the attachment capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming CFULLPATH is your attachment field?

If that's true, then I believe you can just append .Filename to the attachment field to display the path in the query

```
CLIENT_DETAILS.CFULLPATH.Filename
```